# How to put data from a database into an Arraylist?

Tags: java, sql, arraylist

What I'm trying to do is to put data from my database into an Arraylist.

I have a database with wamp, and a simple table: Player, which has a name and a score.

I'm trying to get all of those player into a ArrayList, but what I've tried did not work because my ArrayList is a Player type, and the type which I enter is a String and int.

Here is the code I have for now:

```
public int test1() {
    try {
        ArrayList<Player> playerList= new ArrayList<Player>();
        BD=ds.getConnection();
        Statement s = BD.createStatement();
        ResultSet p = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM player");
        int i = 0;
        while(p.next()) {
            i++;
            playerList.add(p.getString("name")); //did not work
            playerList.add(p.getInt("score");
        }
        s.close();
        BD.close();
        return 1;
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) {

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is someone know something on how to do it, I'll be very thanksfull.

Cordially

Comment: `playerList.add(new Player(p.getString("name"), p.getInt("score")));` perhaps?

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to add a String and an int to a List that is allowed to only accept a Player object. So create a Player object with the data on hand, and add it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The playerList will only accept a Player object, not a String or an int. So create a Player object with the data on hand, and then add it to the list:

```
while(p.next()) {
    i++;
    String name = p.getString("name");
    int score = p.getInt("score");
    Player player = new Player(name, score); // assuming such a constructor exists

    // playerList.add(p.getString("name")); //did not work
    // playerList.add(p.getInt("score");

    // do this:
    playerList.add(player);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a List of Players, and you are trying to add a String and a Integer into it.

```
ArrayList<Player> playerList= new ArrayList<Player>();
...
      playerList.add(p.getString("name")); //did not work
      playerList.add(p.getInt("score");
...
```

You can follow @Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestion and create a new Player before adding to the list:

```
Player player = new Player(p.getString("name"), p.getInt("score"));
playerList.add(player);
```